# Proof that a random variable is continuous

Tags: probability

I am attempting to show that the below random variable has no atoms:

$X = \sum_n \frac{\beta_{n}}{3^{n}}$, where $\beta_n$ is $0$ or $2$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** With probability $1$, $\ X\ $ is an irrational number in the interval $\ [0,1]\ $ (if the sum starts at $\ n=1\ $) or $\ [0,3]\ $ (if it starts at $\ n=0\ $), the digits of whose ternary expansion are all $0$s or $2$s. Let $\ a\ $ be any such number, and $\ \sum_n\frac{a_n}{3^n}\ $ its ternary expansion.  What is the probability that $\ X=a\ $?

Comment: Just to clarify, $\Sigma_{n}\frac{a_{n}}{3}$ is the ternary expansion of a number $a$, which is already the ternary expansion of $\beta_{n}$? Why is this helpful?

Comment: It is only the ternary expansion of $\ X\ $ when $\ X=a\ $, a *random* event whose probability you can easily calculate, because (whenever $\ a\ $ doesn't have a terminating ternary expansion) it's just the event $\ \bigcap_\limits{n}\left\{\beta_n=\alpha_n\right\}\ $.  What is the probability of that event?